# Use returned array from $scope function in the controller

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope

In my controller I have created `$scope` `function` which returns an `array`. That `function` uses data from view with `ng-model` directive and everything is working fine (when I call this function with the expression in the view I get returned data), **except** when I want to use that returned `array` in my controller, I simply get nothing.

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TsomEymUWADofNf8NZfZ?p=info)**

**JS** code:

```
app.controller('CalculatorCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.deparature = {
    'lat_1': '',
    'lat_2': '',
    'lat_3': '',
    'long_1': '',
    'long_2': '',
    'long_3': ''
  }

  $scope.arrival = {
    'lat_1': '',
    'lat_2': '',
    'lat_3': '',
    'long_1': '',
    'long_2': '',
    'long_3': ''
  }

  $scope.select = {
    'departure_1': '',
    'departure_2': '',
    'arrival_1': '',
    'arrival_2': ''
  }

  $scope.depCoordinate = function() {

    var cordLat = $scope.deparature.lat_1 + '/' + $scope.deparature.lat_2 + '/' + $scope.deparature.lat_3 + '/';

    if ($scope.select.departure_1 === 'S') {
      var temp = '-' + cordLat;
      var CordLatS = Dms.parseDMS(temp);
    } else {
      var CordLatS = Dms.parseDMS(cordLat);
    };

    var cordLong = $scope.deparature.long_1 + '/' + $scope.deparature.long_2 + '/' + $scope.deparature.long_3 + '/';

    if ($scope.select.departure_2 === 'W') {
      var temp = '-' + cordLong;
      var CordLongW = Dms.parseDMS(temp);
    } else {
      var CordLongW = Dms.parseDMS(cordLong);
    };

    return [CordLatS.toFixed(5), CordLongW.toFixed(5)];
  }

  var cord = $scope.depCoordinate();
  var lati = cord[0];
  console.log(lati);

  /*I need to pass the array result to var p1. How I can do that?*/
  $scope.distance = function () {
      var p1 = new LatLon(50.06632, -5.71475);
      var p2 = new LatLon(58.64402, -3.07009);
      return p1.distanceTo(p2);

};
});
```

Comment: Could you update your question with the pertinent HTML so that we can get a better idea of how it all works together?  Also, a plunker would be nice.

Comment: Also, what is Dms?  You are using it but I don't see where it is defined or injected.

Comment: I edited the post and added Plunker link with HTML code and controller. DMS is used from some third party library, that part works fine.

Comment: **NEVER** do this: `<p>Test: {{ depCoordinate() }}</p>`. It will call your function several times causing several problems. Put a `console.log('anything');` and see yourself. `ng-init()` should be used only in specific cases (i.e. `ng-repeat`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there are some things in your *plunker* that should be relevant here:

1. **NEVER** do this: `<p>Test: {{ depCoordinate() }}</p>`.

It will call your function several times causing several problems.

2. Don't use `ng-init()` for this kind of thing: `<div class="list" ng-init="initWaves()">`. It should be used only in specific cases (i.e. ng-repeat), check the [**docs**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit).

Then.. If I understood your question well, you want to use the `returned` `array` in your view, so, if I'm correct, here is *how-to*:

```
$scope.array = [CordLatS.toFixed(5), CordLongW.toFixed(5)];
return $scope.array;
```

And in your **view** just use it:

`{{ array }}` // or whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I just misspoke about my problems... I want to save value from that array in some variable so that they could later use as an argument to another function. Basiclly i want to save input data from my view so later I can calculate all other stuff.

Comment: So it's done, as I explained you can use it `{{ array }}` for example.

Comment: Did you got what I said?

Comment: Yes, I try it and it's works for view. But hove I can use that array in controller for other functions? I understand that when is view load they automatically start controller and execute $scope.depCoordinate function. So when its array is call in view I see results.
But the main question is how I can get that array in controller?

PS. I edited the post and added function which I need (with comments)

Comment: Doesn't it work? `var p1 = new LatLon($scope.array[0], $scope.array[1]);`

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean that "I get nothing"? As far as I see, you wrote `$scope.depCoordinate();` on init state of controller. When your controller is executed, that function will work immediately.

I think problem is that initial state. Because you don't have any data on first creation of controller. All of your variables are ''.

So, what you want to do exactly? You can use ngChange directive on your view layer with element which are updating that variables (deparature, arrival, select) with a function that is for watching updates. Then you need to write a function into your controller as follows;

```
$scope.watchChanges = function() {
  var cord = $scope.depCoordinate();
  var lati = cord[0];
};
```